# jquery validation for modal popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
<script>
function submitAddStudent() {
 $("#modalForm").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        letterswithspace: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      phone: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        digits: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name: {
        required: "Please enter a name.",
        letterswithspace: "Please enter a valid name with letters and spaces only."
      },
      email: {
        required: "Please enter an email address.",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
      },
      phone: {
        required: "Please enter a phone number.",
        minlength: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.",
        maxlength: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.",
        digits: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number."
      }
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    }
  });

}
</script>
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/wxber8yp/1/
Included HTML, and Script file in above link for your reference.

In the modal popup form its not validate the form fields and I can't add student (Add Student) button is not working inside the modal popup. I am expecting the form should validate by jquery validation and it should add the data into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few errors in your code.

1. You forgot to include validate js in your html
2. You were calling validate on modal. It should be on form. For this i have added id as myForm to form.
3. The button should have type submit
4. Form should wrap all your element and buttons

```js
$("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {
    inputName: {
      required: true,
      letterswithspace: true
    },
    inputEmail: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    inputPhone: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 10,
      digits: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    inputName: {
      required: "Please enter a name.",
      letterswithspace: "Please enter a valid name with letters and spaces only."
    },
    inputEmail: {
      required: "Please enter an email address.",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },
    inputPhone: {
      required: "Please enter a phone number.",
      minlength: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.",
      maxlength: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.",
      digits: "Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number."
    }
  },
  errorElement: "span",
  errorClass: "help-block",
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    var name = document.getElementById("inputName").value.trim();
    var email = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value.trim();
    var phone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value.trim();
    var student_id = document.getElementById("inputstudent_id").value.trim();
    var status = document.getElementById("status").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "add_students.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        // window.location.reload();
        $('#modalForm').modal('hide');
        var table = $('#studentsTable').DataTable();
        table.ajax.reload();
      }
    };
    xhr.send("name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&student_id=" + student_id + "&status=" + status);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="add-student-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm">
      Add Student
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form role="form" id='myForm'>
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Student</h4>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="statusMsg"></p>            
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" name="
inputName" placeholder="Enter the Name here" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter the email here" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="inputPhone" name="inputPhone" placeholder="Enter the Phone Number here" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputstudent_id">Student ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputstudent_id" name="inputstudent_id" placeholder="Enter the Student ID here" />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status:</label>
                <select id="status" name="status">
                  <option value="Active">Active</option>
                  <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                </select>
              </div>            
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn">Add Student</button>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```